# executing two spaces between two words

Tags: php, mysql, string

In my db table, two spaces in between two words.
For example (Hello 2spaces World).
I want to fetch as it is, but when PHP execute the script it removes one extra space. Like (Hello 1space World), but I need as it is.
Please help me out.

Comment: What about 3 spaces? Or 4? or 10?

Comment: @austin only two spaces is there. 3 or 4 will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

HTML prints regular white space as 1 space, unless you specify more with the ASCII code. You'll need to replace the spaces with the code:

```
$string = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;', $string);
```

If you only want to replace the double spaces, tweak the str_replace like this:

```
$string = str_replace('  ','&nbsp;&nbsp;', $string);
```

Comment: it will take two spaces in every two words. but I want it as it is in DB.only one row value has two spaces. rest is fine.

Comment: If you only want to fix the 2 spaces you can tweak the str_replace to be `$string = str_replace('  ','&nbsp;&nbsp;', $string);` Actually, let me add that to the answer, since it looks weird in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, another way to combat this would be to place all your text within a set of PRE tags, and then it will display exactly as is.